# Selenium Chromedriver Doesn't Work - Java, Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My project was fine until this suddenly happened

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 96
Current browser version is 98.0.4758.102 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

I downloaded the latest version then but, it still shows the same error which doesn't make sense. The error message should've at least changed. I wonder what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I just realized that I accidentally set two environment variables that points to chromedriver.exe that exist in different folders.